# Why does my pan gesture only nudge its view and stop?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

Here is the UIPanGesture subclass:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touches began");
   self ->origLoc = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view.superview];
   [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
    CGPoint loc = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view.superview];
    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(loc.x - origLoc.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(loc.y - origLoc.y);
    if (deltaY >= deltaX) {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    } else {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
}

- (CGPoint) translationInView:(UIView *)v {

CGPoint proposedTranslation = [super translationInView:v];
proposedTranslation.y = 0;
return proposedTranslation;

}
```

Here is the method that gets called by my subclassed UIPanGesture:

```
- (void)dragging: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)p {    

UIView *vv = p.view;

if (p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint delta = [p translationInView:vv.superview];
    CGPoint c = vv.center;
    c.x += delta.x;
    c.y += delta.y;
    vv.center = c;
    [p setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:vv.superview];
 }    
}
```

When I try to drag my view around, it just moves a very small amount and then stops. I need to keep nudging it to get it to move. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Michael.

Comment: danh is probably going down the right line of thought. Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do with this subclassed pan gesture recognizer? If you're just trying to pan left and right, there are easier ways to solve that problem. Or do you have some other pan gesture recognizer handling vertical movement and you're trying to detect which gesture recognizer to use? But I would have thought that once you locked into a particular recognizer, you'd stop further checking for swipe direction (to allow for minor changes from minute finger movements).

Comment: It is acting on a cell in GMGridView (a UIScrollview) and I just want to be able to pan the content within one of the cells left or right if a horizontal pan is detected, and scroll the entire view if a vertical pan is detected. You mention I should stop checking for swipe direction, how can I do that?

Comment: Bottom line, have one variable that keeps track of whether you've confirmed whether you checked for the direction of the initial motion, and another that tells you if it was horizontal or not. You then can just check that variable that keeps track of whether the initial movement was horizontal or not to determine whether you change the state to UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed or not. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my prior comments, I wasn't clear why you were subclassing, but you clarified and it's because you have multiple gesture handlers going on. Very good.

So here is some sample code for a custom pan gesture, HorizontalPanGestureRecognizer, which is triggered only if the first movement is horizontal:

```
// HorizontalPanGestureRecognizer.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HorizontalPanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer
@end
```

And

```
// HorizontalPanGestureRecognizer.m

#import "HorizontalPanGestureRecognizer.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface HorizontalPanGestureRecognizer ()
{
    BOOL _hasConfirmedDirection;
    BOOL _wasHorizontal;
    CGPoint _origLoc;
}
@end

@implementation HorizontalPanGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    _hasConfirmedDirection = NO;

    _origLoc = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) return;

    if (!_hasConfirmedDirection)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [self translationInView:self.view];

        _hasConfirmedDirection = YES;
        _wasHorizontal = (fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y));
    }
    if (!_wasHorizontal)
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    if (!_wasHorizontal)
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];

    if (!_wasHorizontal)
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGPoint superLocation = [super locationInView:view];

    if (_hasConfirmedDirection)
        superLocation.y = _origLoc.y;

    return superLocation;
}

- (CGPoint)translationInView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGPoint superTranslation = [super translationInView:view];

    if (_hasConfirmedDirection)
        superTranslation.y = 0.0f;

    return superTranslation;
}

@end
```

And then you can have your handler in your main view controller use it appropriately (in this example, just dragging a UILabel around). In in viewDidLoad, create the gesture:

```
HorizontalPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[HorizontalPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleCustomPan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

And then the handler would look something like:

```
- (void)handleCustomPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{    
    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            if (!_panLabel)
            {
                // In my case I'm creating a UILabel to drag around, whereas you might just drag
                // whatever countrol you want to drag.
                //
                // But, regardless, I'm keeping track of the original center in _panLabelOrigCenter

                [self makePanLabel:sender]; 
            }

            CGPoint translate = [sender translationInView:self.view];
            _panLabel.center = CGPointMake(_panLabelOrigCenter.x + translate.x, _panLabelOrigCenter.y + translate.y);

            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            [self removePanLabel];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

(Obviously, this is ARC code. If non-ARC, add the necessary additional lines of code for routine memory management.)

Comment: Hi Rob , I just trying to use above but getting two erros 1. 
No visible @interface for 'UIPanGestureRecognizer' declares the selector 'touchesEnded:withEvent:'      2.  Assignment to readonly property Can you plz help out.

Comment: @PavanMore You have to `#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>` (it's a header to be used when subclassing a gesture recognizer, exposing some otherwise private methods as well as making some typically `readonly` properties as `readwrite`). Sorry that that wasn't clear, and I've attempted to clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That failure condition in touches moved looks like it will be super sensitive to early motion.

Consider making it less sensitive ...

```
- (BOOL)movementIsHorizontalX:(CGFloat)x andY:(CGFloat) y {

    CGFloat absX = fabs(x);
    CGFloat absY = fabs(y);

    // if x is small, then accept small y values but not large ones
    if (absX < 4) return absY < 4;

    // now we can express horizontal-ness as a slope.  we've ruled out small x, so this is a stable calculation
    CGFloat slope = absY / absX;
    return slope < 0.10;

    // you could generalize by passing in the x threshold and percentage slope constants
}
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Is there a better place to put that check? I would love for the view to only accept horizontal movement and prevent vertical scrolling of the superview (UIScrollView). Unless the scroll is initially vertical than the superview can scroll and the horizontal movement can be ignored.

Comment: I think it's a good place to check, but we can improve the test.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your responses so far. I now have the following, see below:

Comment: I am still getting just nudges with those changes to code. I added an NSLog in dragging and it is indeed calling that method repeatedly but the view stops moving after a very brief nudge.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my error. I moved

```
    [super touchesMoved: touches withEvent:event];
```

outside the if statement, and now it seems to work fine. Not really 100% sure why it works now, but I am happy it does.

Now to figure out how to prevent the UIScrollView from accepting the pan gesture until this one cancels/fails...

Comment: The code I included in my answer handles the pan if horizontally initiated (and thus the UITableView's gesture recognizer does not get it), but ignores it and passes it on to the tableview's standard gesture recognized if vertically initiated. If I've misunderstood what you are trying to do, let me know.